Understanding DISPLAY and Xservers on Ubuntu
I have been having a rough time trying to fix a once working WSL2 system that could display the GUI of linux apps on windows. Previously I was using a third party app/xserver called GWSL, but one fine day I uninstalled Docker Desktop on Windows for some unrelated reason, and that somehow broke everything.
I have since learned that the current version of WSL comes with its own graphics support, (WSLG) from Microsoft themselves, and I have been able to launch any app installed on Ubuntu like google-chrome etc, with one initial step required.
I'm still utterly confused about all of this x server and DISPLAY stuff in general, and the only thing I care about is getting Playwright to launch a browser to test some web stuff, but it keeps giving me this error
Looks like you launched a headed browser without having a XServer running.                    
Set either 'headless: true' or use 'xvfb-run <your-playwright-app>

So I'm not looking for help with Playwright, but rather trying to understand what is going on.
When I boot up Ubuntu on WSL2 and run
ps e | grep -Po " DISPLAY=[\.0-9A-Za-z:]* " | sort -u
I get
 DISPLAY=10.255.255.254:0.0
 DISPLAY=:0

Does this mean I have two displays? I guess so.
When I run echo $DISPLAY I get 10.255.255.254:0.0
When I then run google-chrome I get Missing X server or $DISPLAY
When I then run export DISPLAY=:0 I can then successfully run not only google-chrome but Playwrights version of chromium (found me\.cache\ms-playwright\chromium-1134\chrome-linux\chrome) without issue.
Yet, when I try to run Playwright tests again, it's still telling me I have no XServer running.
So at this point, I am trying to understand what state I am in. Do I really have no XServer running if I can actually launch chrome et al through Ubuntu and see it on my Windows desktop? Do I have the wrong or too many DISPLAYs? Do we think Playwright only works on a specific DISPLAY or XServer (port? ip?). I am a bit clueless here and am not sure what else to debug. I've installed and run about 1000 linux commands and have tried various windows 3rd party xservers. It seems like it's kind of working, just not for Playwright.

The X11 display name has the following general format:
[hostname_or_IP]:<display number>[.screen number]

The hostname and the screen number parts are optional: if hostname is left empty, it means the local host. If the screen number is left out, screen 0 is assumed.
An X11 display is a collection of input devices (usually a keyboard and a mouse) and one or more physical screens, all under control of a single user session at a time. A computer can have multiple X11 displays for a multitude of reasons: for example, it may support the X11 equivalent of Windows's fast user switching, or it might host remote VNC or RDP sessions, or it might be a true multi-seat system: one that allows two or more local users to log in and have independent GUI sessions at the same time.
An X11 screen is a display device with particular properties. Back when CRTs were the state of the art in display technology, a professional CAD workstation might have had one high-refresh-rate grayscale monitor to minimize eye fatigue, and another monitor optimized for high-fidelity color display for viewing the rendered results.
On modern flat-panel displays, full-color is the norm and refresh rate does not affect eye fatigue (at least with still images), and so it's more common to have multiple physical monitors be represented as a single X11 screen that spans them both. This allows moving windows freely from one monitor to another. Thus, having screen numbers greater than 0 would be quite unexpected on modern systems.
DISPLAY=10.255.255.254:0.0

means "contact the display 0, screen 0 of the X11 display server using a TCP connection to IP address 10.255.255.254, port number 6000 (= display number + 6000)". The screen number (the last .0 bit) is optional; if not specified, screen 0 is used.
DISPLAY=:0

means "contact the display 0, default screen 0 of the local machine, using the most efficient transport mechanism available". In Linux, this would usually mean the application would initially contact the display server using a UNIX socket located in /tmp/.X11-unix/X0, and optionally negotiating shared memory access to the X11 server (MIT-SHM X11 protocol extension) and/or Direct Rendering (direct GPU access; XFree86-DGA or DRI extensions) for improved performance if needed and available.
If 10.255.255.254 is the IP address of your local system, then both of these DISPLAY specifications tell the client to connect to the same X11 display, but probably using different transport methods.
The first form forces TCP to be used even locally; this results in a performance penalty, but makes it easier to e.g. record the session.
The second form may fall back to using TCP anyway, if the UNIX socket matching the display number is not available, and the X11 server is listening on the local TCP port (display number + 6000).
In modern Linux, X11 servers usually only provide the UNIX socket by default, as using the TCP-based connections X11 connections without SSH X11 forwarding or some other encryption layer over an actual network connection is horribly insecure by modern standards.
Since Windows-based X11 servers used to be mostly used for accessing remote X11 displays, they tend to have TCP-based connections enabled by default, and that might even be their only available connection method.

The fact that the DISPLAY variable is set suggests something in your system is set to assume the X11 server is available. But the error message
Looks like you launched a headed browser without having a XServer running.                    
Set either 'headless: true' or use 'xvfb-run <your-playwright-app>

suggest it is not actually available now; either it is not running, or something prevents the applications from contacting it.
The xvfb-run is probably a script that runs the specified app with a Virtual Frame Buffer X11 server: a sort of dummy X11 server that is not actually connected to any visible display, but behaves as if it was.
WSLg further complicates the issue because apparently it is implemented as a RDP-accessible Wayland display server with an XWayland X11 compatibility layer on top of it.
For WSLg to work, you apparently should be connecting to the WSL2 system using RDP. Then, you could test with a native Wayland application like gnome-terminal first. If that works, then the core Wayland display server is running, at least.
If that works, the next step would be to verify that the /tmp/.X11-unix/X<display number> UNIX socket is present and the XWayland process is running, or is configured to start using systemd's socket activation feature when a X11 client attempts to use the socket. fuser /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 should tell the PID(s) of the process(es) currently associated with the socket.
For DISPLAY=10.255.255.254:0.0 to work, you would first have to verify that there is a X11 server process listening on TCP port 6000 in that IP address. If the address belongs to the WSL2 system, lsof -i tcp:6000 should confirm whether or not the X11 server (or the XWayland compatibility layer) is actually listening on that port. With nc -v 10.255.255.254 6000 you could test whether the port is actually connectable or not (software firewalls?).
XWayland might not listen on a TCP port by default, but Playwright might provide a X11 proxy for it. (Disclaimer: I have no clue how Playwright actually works.)

Thanks for your amazing answer. To answer some of your queries: I can easily run gnome-terminal among any other app installed on WSL. However, none of the other commands you provided return anything at all. fuser /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 outputs nothing. lsof -i tcp:6000 outputs nothing. nc -v 10.255.255.254 6000 fails. - A perplexing thing to me is, the change I made (conceivably) was on the Windows side when I removed Docker Desktop for unrelated reasons. So it really does look like I don't have an XServer running... but then how on earth did it run before. Maybe some networking shenanigans

It seems you probably relied on Windows-side X11 server, and removing the Docker Desktop may have changed the network configuration or caused some other changes that disabled the connection from WSL2 to that X11 server. At a guess, you might run locate xwayland.service or locate xwayland.socket to see if you have any files like that: if they exist, use systemctl status <service or socket name> to see if the respective service/socket has been disabled or masked. If so, unmasking/enabling them might fix the problem.

A hmm, yeah, honestly I feel FUBARd here. I started following this guide which I don't even know if it's out of date, but I noticed that I don't have this sym link described by ls -la /tmp/.X11-unix. After some head smashing with a read-only issue, I was able to create the link. Running the rest of the diagnostic commands, everything prints out the same as described, so X server is in fact running... but only playwright cannot launch Chromium.. so it feels like a network issue now.

Well I appreciate the help. I ended up installing a new WSL with ubuntu at 24, and now everything works.
